# Issue with nested asynchronous function not returning data in time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I rely on a component i.e. [Angular Material Autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete) that requires a function **that returns a value**.

Unfortunately, I am not sure how to return something in due time from the nested asynchronous function below (`addressAutocomplete()`):

```
$scope.chooseAddress = function (input) {
    var results = [];
    if (input) {
        geolocationService.addressAutocomplete(input, function (data) {
            results = data.predictions;//Will be fired asynchronously and too late...
        });
    }
    return results;//I have to return something from my function...
};
```

By the time the addressAutocomplete function has completed, the `results` var has already been returned and it is of course an empty array...

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expose the fact that the call is asynchronous to the callees of `chooseAddress`. You can achieve this by returning a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Update the implementation to

```
$scope.chooseAddress = function (input) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (input) {
        geolocationService.addressAutocomplete(input, function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data.predictions);
        });
    } else {
        deferred.resolve([]);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

You then call `chooseAddress` like

```
$scope.chooseAddress(input).then(function(result){
    // the result will be available here
});
```